# Getting Return from an DB.ALL called

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sqlite

Trying to get the rows values from the DB all function. Unable to get that out of the DB.All function or pull it away from the arrow. The console log that I got will return the output I desire but I want it pull it out so I can use the JSON value.

Any idea how to do this?

```js
handler: (request, h) => {
        let sql = `SELECT TRIAL_ID as indexTrial, URL as urlImage FROM TRIAL`;
        var test ='hi';


            db.all(sql, (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                test= JSON.stringify(rows);
                console.log(test);
                test =rows;
                //return rows;
            });


        return test;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Needed a promise because it was going to fast to get the value

```
handler: (request, h) => {
    let sql = `SELECT TRIAL_ID as indexTrial, URL as urlImage FROM TRIAL`;
    var result =[];
    var test ='hi';

return new Promise((resolve) => {
    db.all(sql,[], (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            resolve(rows);

        })
}).then((rows) => {
    return h.response(rows);
});
```